# Multiplicative Inverse Modulo N.

Tags: number-theory

I would like to be able to figure out the multiplicative inverse of some integer modulo some N.

For example, how would I find ${15^{ - 1}}$ modulo 34. Will these always exist? If not, what dictates whether they exist or not?

Comment: Hint: the multiples of $15$ are $0 , 15 , 30 , 11 , 26 , 7 , 22 , 3 , 18 , 33 , 14 , 29 , 10 , 25 , 6 , 21 , 2 , 17 , 32 , 13 , 28 , 9 , 24 , 5 , 20 , \color{green}1 , 16 , 31 , 12 , 27 , 8 , 23 , 4 , 19.$

Answer (score 1):

If $m$ and $n$ are coprime, then $m$ will always have a multiplicative inverse mod $n$.

You can use [the Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Description) to efficiently get an expression of the form $am + bn = 1$. Reducing this mod $n$ we get $am \equiv 1 \pmod n$, that is $a \equiv b^{-1} \pmod n$.

In your example, we run Euclid's algorithm to get:

1. $34 = 2 \cdot 15 + 4$
2. $15 = 3 \cdot 4 + 3$
3. $ 4 = 1 \cdot 3 + 1$

and working backwards we obtain:

1. $1 = 4 - 3$
2. $1 = 4 - (15 - 3 \cdot 4) = 4 \cdot 4 - 15$
3. $1 = 4 \cdot (34 - 2 \cdot 15) - 15 = 4 \cdot 34 - 9 \cdot 15$

and so conclude that $-9 = 15^{-1} \pmod {34}$ negative because it is minus 9.